# JPA Persistence error Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am developing a Spring Server an I am using JPA and CrudRepositories to save.
I am trying to store a list of "Completed_survey" classes like this:

`@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER) 
 List<Completed_survey> list_completed_survey = new ArrayList<Completed_survey>();`

Where `Completed_survey` is this simple class:

```
 @Entity
 public class Completed_survey {
   List<String> answer = new ArrayList<String>();
   public Completed_survey()
   {
   }
   public List<String> getAnswer() 
   {
         return answer;
   }
   public void setAnswer(List<String> answer) 
   {
         this.answer = answer;
   }
}
```

But this error appears:

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class palmaslab.mapas.config.Application: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1554)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:975)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:752)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
at palmaslab.mapas.config.Application.main(Application.java:71)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1239)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:120)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:855)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:338)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1550)
... 15 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: palmaslab.mapas.repository.Completed_survey
at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:277)
at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:224)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:775)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3845)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3799)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1412)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852)
... 23 more
```

Any solution?Thank you

Comment: What have you done to try and resolve this? Are you focusing on `org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type` ?

Comment: Yes i am focused in this line but I dont know how to resolve it. I did something similar in the past and it never gave me this error.

Comment: Is that column in your database a `String`?

Comment: I have added this peace of code now. So before that, this column didn't exist. To solve that i have changed the application.properties file like that `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/test;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql: true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop` in order to delete the database and create a new one with this new column. I dont know how to check if this column is a String or not...

Comment: It builds fine but when you try to save it breaks or is the error from when it tries to create the new database schema?

Comment: when it tries to create the new database schema, it breaks. I have done an Update. I have put a @Entity in my "Completed_survey" class and a similar error appears.

Comment: I didnt want to put and @entity and an identifer for this class thinking that maybe it would waste so storage but doing that all seems to works normally.